# Multiple Dropdowns - onclick not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The current implementation allows the use of select boxes and converts them into list items so they can be styled.

The problem is that once you open a dropdown, the only way to close is by clicking the document OR another dropdown menu.

Does anyone have any recommendations on the best way of going about this as the reason behind is that to ensure that if someone clicks on another dropdown item, the current one should toggle off. But if you click on the current item only, the toggle can only activate it, not deactivate it.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
(function (jq) {

    // Iterate over each select element
    jq('.selectBoxStyle').each(function () {

        // Cache the number of options
        var sthis = jq(this),
            numberOfOptions = jq(this).children('option').length;

        // Hides the select element

        if (jq('html').hasClass('touch')) {

            jq('.options').addClass('s-hidden');

            sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

            // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
            sthis.wrap('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');


        } else {

            sthis.addClass('s-hidden');

            // Wrap the select element in a div
            sthis.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

            // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
            sthis.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

            // Cache the styled div
            var styledSelect = sthis.next('div.styledSelect');

            // Show the first select option in the styled div
            styledSelect.text(sthis.children('option').eq(0).text());

            // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
            var slist = jq('<ul />', {
                'class': 'options'
            }).insertAfter(styledSelect);

            // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
                jq('<li />', {
                    text: sthis.children('option').eq(i).text(),
                        "data-value": sthis.children('option').eq(i).val(),
                        "class": sthis.children('option').eq(i).attr('class'),
                        "data-sku": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('sku'),
                        "data-stock": sthis.children('option').eq(i).data('stock')
                }).appendTo(slist);
            }

            // Cache the list items
            var slistItems = slist.children('li');

            // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)

            styledSelect.click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                //jq(this).toggleClass('clickme').removeClass('active');

                jq('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
                    jq(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
                    console.log(this);
                });

                jq(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();


            });

            // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
            // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
            slistItems.click(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                styledSelect.text(jq(this).text()).removeClass('active');
                jq(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
                sthis.val(jq(this).attr('value'));
                slist.hide();
                /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
            });

            // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
            jq(document).click(function () {
                styledSelect.removeClass('active');
                slist.hide();
            });
        }



    });
}(jq));
```

```css
body {
    background-color:white;
}
.selectSizeMain {
    width: 56.77966%;
    float: none;
    margin: 2.1875rem auto auto;
}
.s-hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.select {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    color:black;
    font-family: GibsonRegular, HelveticaNeue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: .875rem;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.styledSelect {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding: 11px 13px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.styledSelect:after {
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-color:black transparent transparent transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top: 17px;
    right: 9px;
}
.styledSelect.active:after {
    content:"";
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:5px solid transparent;
    border-color:green transparent transparent transparent;
    position:absolute;
    top: 17px;
    right: 9px;
}
.options {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    top:100%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:999;
    margin:0 0;
    padding:0 0;
    list-style:none;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:none;
    background-color:white;
}
.options li {
    padding: 11px 13px;
    margin:0 0;
}
.options li:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selectSizeMain">
    <select class="selectBoxStyle">
        <option value="">Choose Size</option>
        <option value="aye">Aye</option>
        <option value="eh">Eh</option>
        <option value="ooh">Ooh</option>
        <option value="whoop">Whoop</option>
    </select>
</div>
<select class="selectBoxStyle">
    <option value="">Month&hellip;</option>
    <option value="january">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just ran your snippet and it seems to be closing on select. Could you rephrase your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could achieve this is to check if the clicked select already has the `.active` class - then, after closing all the presently open selects, you can determine whether or not you should use `toggleClass("active")` on it.

So your callback would turn from this:

```
styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    jq('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
        jq(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        console.log(this);
    });

    jq(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
});
```

to this:

```
styledSelect.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var closeClicked = jq(this).hasClass("active");

    jq('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
        jq(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        console.log(this);
    });

    if (!closeClicked){
        jq(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    }    
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3qwf2pg/) to demonstrate. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works and only requires a minor change to your current code. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.